# a base image cannot be pulled in Dockerfile but can be pulled by docker pull command

Tags: dockerfile, docker-registry

I ran into an issue: I specified base image `FROM openjdk:8-jdk-slim`
docker build reports an issue

```
$ docker build .
#2 [internal] load .dockerignore
#2 sha256:2c93e14eb3549bf8ce40ea8e6e0a0fb6a24a64f2fffa6c030b807e817981ff59
#2 transferring context: 2B 0.0s done
#2 DONE 0.1s

#1 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
#1 sha256:91b2fa387ccc0f9f6bbda90d53cf9582e2aef62a4496456a63fd784cf2943f93
#1 transferring dockerfile: 1.02kB 0.1s done
#1 DONE 0.2s

#3 [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/openjdk:8-jdk-slim
#3 sha256:14693bdc7fcd16ee4b599f8ecd52de3ef039c0f424e644564425aa0a983eee2c
#3 ERROR: failed to authorize: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to fetch anonymous token: Get "https://auth.docker.io/token?scope=repository%3Alibrary%2Fopenjdk%3Apull&service=registry.docker.io": dial tcp 3.228.155.36:443: i/o timeout
------
 > [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/openjdk:8-jdk-slim:
------
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: failed to authorize: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to fetch anonymous token: Get "https://auth.docker.io/token?scope=repository%3Alibrary%2Fopenjdk%3Apull&service=registry.docker.io": dial tcp 3.228.155.36:443: i/o timeout
```

However `docker pull openjdk:8-jdk-slim` is successfull

I assume it's the same docker pull but I don't understand why one failed while the other succeeded.

Comment: I'd bet this is a transient error. Did you retry a bit later ? Are you still facing the exact same error ?

Comment: Hi @Zeitounator, it's not temporary, I constantly reproduce this issue in my environment. Very strange.

Comment: I also have this issue but I have found it has something to do with my company's networking/proxy/dns settings.  Works on my vpn'ed laptop but fails when remote desktoped into "internal" workstataion.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue when I used the buildx tool to build a docker image for a different environment. To build the container for different environments, docker spawns a build-kit container. If your PC has been running this container for a while during network switches, the container can lose the connection to the internet, resulting in such an error. Simply removing the running container and re-running the build command worked for me, as it respawns a fresh build-kit container with proper network connections to build the docker file.